# Creating/Editing entity using a View in C# MVC without

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have a View in which I use a `@Html.EditorForModel()`, to create and edit information in the SQL table. With this, I have limited functionality, so I thought I would use some sort of bootstrap to get the layout of TextBoxes a bit neater.

I removed (commented) the EditotForModel, added my own styled TextBoxes. It looks great, but the Save is not successful. It throws out an error as

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

This is my View (Book.cshtml),

```
@model PEF.IT.BoilerTest.Domain.CustomerModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add";
}
<h3><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Customer Information</span></h3>
<br />
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveCustomer", "Companies"))
{
    @*@Html.EditorForModel()*@
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Customer Name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="CustomerName"><br />

    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Address Line 1" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="AddressLine1"><br />

    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Postcode" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="Postcode"><br />

    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="PhoneNo"><br />

    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Boiler Name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="BoilerName"><br />

    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Boiler Age" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="BoilerAge"><br/>

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">£</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="72.55" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="ServiceRate">
    </div><br />

    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="17/03/2015" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="ServiceDate"><br/>

    <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>

    @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-warning" })
}
```

This is my controller,

```
    //Customers
    public ActionResult Book(long id)
    {
        return View(new CustomerModel
        {
            CompanyId = id
        });
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveCustomer(CustomerModel model)
    {
        _companyService.SaveCustomer(model);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

This is the Save Method in the Service,

```
//Save a Customer
public void SaveCustomer(CustomerModel customer)
{
    using (var db = new BoilerServicingDbContext())
    {
        Customer entity;
        if (customer.CustomerId > 0)
        {
            entity = db.Customers.First(x => x.Id == customer.CustomerId);
        }
        else
        {
            entity = new Customer();
            db.Customers.Add(entity);

            //Fails here. If I used Editor For Model, no problem.
            var p = Map(db.Companies.AsNoTracking()).First(x => x.CompanyId == customer.CompanyId);

            var fromAddress = new MailAddress("someone@gmail.com", "Name");
            var toAddress = new MailAddress("someone2@gmail.com", "Name2");//new MailAddress(p.Email, p.CompanyName);
            const string fromPassword = "XXXX";
            const string subject = "New Email";

            string body = "<HTML>" +
                                "<BODY>" +
                                    "<P>Dear " + p.CompanyName + ",</P><BR/><BR/>" +
                                    "<P>Hope you are well.<BR/><BR/>" +
                                    "Kind Regards<BR/><BR/>" +
                                    "Name2" +
                                "</BODY>" +
                          "</HTML>";

            var smtp = new SmtpClient
            {
                Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
                Port = 587,
                EnableSsl = true,
                DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
            };
            using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
            {
                Bcc = { "newone@somewhere.com" },
                Subject = subject,
                IsBodyHtml = true,
                Body = body
            })
            {
                smtp.Send(message);
            }
        }

        entity.Name = customer.CustomerName;
        entity.TelephoneNumber = customer.PhoneNo;
        entity.AddressLine1 = customer.AddressLine1;
        entity.PostCode = customer.Postcode;
        entity.CompanyId = customer.CompanyId;
        entity.ServiceDate = customer.ServiceDate;
        entity.ServiceCompleteted = customer.ServiceCompletion;
        entity.BoilerName = customer.BoilerName;
        entity.BoilerAge = customer.BoilerAge;
        entity.ServiceRate = customer.ServiceRate;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's an ADO.NET error, but your sample has no database code; you need to include the code where the exception is being thrown (look at its stack trace).

Comment: @Richard, the error occurs when I am using my own input text boxes, not when I am using the EditorForModel. Also the passed in model seems ot be empty, which explains why `customer.CompanyID` returns that error. The code for the Service is given.

Comment: A database error will involve database code, it might be indirect (LINQ and lazy loading) but it certainly is there. Examining the type and stack trace of the exception will tell you far more.

Comment: On the other hand: as it appears you are using EF, have you set the connection string to enable multiple active recordsets (MARS)?

Comment: I suggest you check the values of the properties `CustomerModel` when you post back - they will all be `null` or the default since you don't post anything back

Comment: @Richard, the Map Function does the LINQ. I am just a bit confused by the fact - why does it work with EditorForModel, but not Input Boxes?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, you are right. So any way how I would be able to get the model to be posted back?

Comment: @PaulFrancis, Your manually rendering the html and your not even giving them `name` attributes so they dont post back. Use the html helpers so you get 2-way binding - `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CustomerName, new { @class="form-control" })`

Comment: That is what I ended up doing. I was typing that as my answer. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work it out, I used `@Html.TextBoxFor`, which gave me what I wanted.

```
@model PEF.IT.BoilerTest.Domain.CustomerModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add";
}
<h3><span style="text-decoration: underline;">Customer Information</span></h3>
<br />
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveCustomer", "Companies"))
{
    @*@Html.EditorForModel()*@

    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.CompanyId, new { type = "hidden" })

    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" style="width: 15em">Customer Name</span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CustomerName, new { @placeholder = "Mr Sam Smith", @class = "form-control", style = "width: 20em" })
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" style="width: 15em">Address Line 1</span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.AddressLine1, new { @placeholder = "23 Greenbank Road", @class = "form-control", style = "width: 20em" })
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="input-group col-sm-10">
        <span class="input-group-addon" style="width: 15em">Postcode</span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Postcode, new { placeholder = "BH1 1JU", @class = "form-control", style = "width: 20em" })
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" style="width: 15em">Phone Number</span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PhoneNo, new { placeholder = "01202 53689", @class = "form-control", style = "width: 20em" })
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" style="width: 15em">Boiler Name &amp; Type</span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.BoilerName, new { placeholder = "Baxi, Gas", @class = "form-control", style = "width: 20em" })
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" style="width: 15em">Agoe Of Boiler</span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.BoilerAge, new { placeholder = "2", @class = "form-control", style = "width: 20em" })
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" style="width: 15em">Service Request Date</span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ServiceDate, new { placeholder = "17/03/2015", @class = "form-control", style = "width: 20em" })
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon" style="width: 15em">Agreed Amount £</span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ServiceRate, new { placeholder = "72.37", @class = "form-control", style = "width: 20em" })
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button><span style="padding-left:2em "></span>
        @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", null, new { @class = "btn btn-warning" })
    </div>
}
```

Appreciate all the response !